# Inserting into Firebase Realtime Database overwrites data instead of appending, how do I get it to append instead of overwriting in js?

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to enter workout information into a Firebase Realtime database from a vue js web app. However, it overwrites data when I try to insert into it. If I enter information for bicep curls and then enter bicep curls again instead of appending it overwrites the original. For example, I want it to be setup like this:

users

- person a

  - bicep curls
    -list of data for different days
  - bench press
    -list of data for different days
- person b

  - bicep curls
    -list of data for different days
  - squats
    -list of data for different days

This is my way of inserting data:

```
writeUserData: function() {
            const db = getDatabase();
            var data = {
                'weight': this.weight,
                'reps': this.reps,
                'sets': this.sets,
                'date': Date(),
            }
            userRef = ref(db, 'users/',  this.name,  this.workoutType);
            set(userRef, [data]);
        },
```

Answer (score 0):

Every time you call `set` with a reference, it replaces any existing data at that `ref`.

If you want to create a new unique child nodes under the ref, use `push` instead of `set`.

```
push(userRef, data)
```

Also see the Firebase documentation on [appending to a list of data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#append_to_a_list_of_data).

Using an array notation like you're trying won't work unless you first read the existing data from the location. Trying to do this is an antipattern in Firebase though, so I also recommend reading [Best Practices: Arrays in Firebase](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html).